# Error (1): The requested resource does not exist Faced, While creating 2nd generation Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, scratch-org, 2gp, beta-managed-package, dev-hub

I am trying to create a second generation beta managed package for learning purpose.

Firstly I have created a namespace org where namespace is present. After that I have created a dev hub org in which I have enabled **dev hub org permission** and added my namespace org in this dev hub org.

Now I created a scratch Org using this dev hub org and done all of my development in this scratch org.
In my development I have created a demo class, demo class's test class and a VF page (all for testing purpose) in this scratch org.

Now I have authorized my Scratch org and taken retrieve of all the components (Class, Test Class and VF page) in VS code.

Apex Class code: -

```
global class DemoAccountClass {

global static void createAccount(){
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Test 1';
    insert acc;
    system.debug('@@ acc -- '+acc.id);
}
```

}

Test Class: -

```
@isTest
public class DemoAccountClass_Test {
@isTest
public static void method1(){
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Test';
    Test.startTest();
    DemoAccountClass.createAccount();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

}

VF Page: -

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton value="Google"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Facebook"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Before creating Managed Package First I have connected my dev hub org and then executed these commands in VS code terminal where scratch org is authorized.

```
sfdx package:create --name Test_Project_123 --path force-app --package-type Managed -- 
target-dev-hub Test_dev
```

After running this command a beta package should be created but I am facing this error -

**Error (1): The requested resource does not exist**

Can anyone suggest any solution, why I am facing this error while creating 2nd generation managed package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Is the dev hub alias valid? If you list orgs is that alias associated with your device hub? 2. Is your code under a folder called force-app and is this folder listed in your sfdx-project.json as a project directory?

Comment: @PhilW Yes it is valid alias.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the content of `sfdx-project.json` (editing any IDs in it to "mask them") - please paste as text like you did for your code samples. It would be good to also illustrate your project's folder structure on disk. And, lastly, did you add the `-meta.xml` files for your metadata items into the folders alongside them?

Comment: Hi @PhilW Thanks for response.
I found the solution. There was a one permission "Enable Unlocked Packages and Second-Generation Managed Packages" which was not enabled by me. I just enabled it and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution on my own. There was a permission in dev hub org **Enable Unlocked Packages and Second-Generation Managed Packages** which was not enabled.

I just enabled it and now everything is working fine.